# asp.Net Gridview shows datatype instead of value

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamics-crm-2011

I've go a little problem and I can't find a solution.

When the gridview is bound all prices will be shown as `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money` instead of its value.

Does anyone know why this happens and how to change it?

Here is my Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ProductList" 
          runat="server" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
          OnRowDataBound="ProductList_OnRowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField 
        HeaderText="Productno." 
        DataField="ProductNumber"/>

    <asp:BoundField 
        HeaderText="Product" 
        DataField="Name" />

    <asp:BoundField 
        HeaderText="Price/Unit" 
        DataField="Price" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and i fill it with teh following code

```
Products = (from ppl in priceCatalog.price_level_product_price_levels
            join prod in ServiceContext.ProductSet.ToList()
                 on ppl.ProductId.Id equals prod.ProductId
            select new Product()
            {
                ProductId = prod.ProductId,
                ProductNumber = prod.ProductNumber,
                Name = prod.Name,
                Price = prod.Price,
                //Price = ppl.Amount.Value,
                PriceLevelId = ppl.PriceLevelId,
                SubjectId = prod.SubjectId,
                DefaultUoMId = ppl.UoMId
            }).ToList();

var product = Products.Where(p => p.SubjectId.Id == filterTo).ToList();

ProductList.DataKeyNames = new[] { "ProductId" };
ProductList.DataSource = product.ToDataTable(XrmContext);
ProductList.DataBind();
```

At the moment it looks like this:

```
PNo.     Name        Price 
1        Prod 1      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money
2        Prod 2      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money
3        Prod 3      Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money
....
```

On xrm.cs( generated file for early bind with CRM)

its following:

```
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("price")]
public System.Nullable<decimal> Price
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetAttributeValue<System.Nullable<decimal>>("price");
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money>("Price", "price", value);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'didnt found a working solution.

what i have done so it works:

I created a new class and at this point i used it. now it works:

```
Products = (from ppl in priceCatalog.price_level_product_price_levels
        join prod in ServiceContext.ProductSet.ToList()
             on ppl.ProductId.Id equals prod.ProductId
        select new ProductClass()
        {
            ProductId = prod.ProductId,
            ProductNumber = prod.ProductNumber,
            Name = prod.Name,
            Price = prod.Price,
            //Price = ppl.Amount.Value,
            PriceLevelId = ppl.PriceLevelId,
            SubjectId = prod.SubjectId,
            DefaultUoMId = ppl.UoMId
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TemplateField` to display the `Value` property (that contains the decimal value) of `Price` field. I added another column to your example

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="ProductList" 
          runat="server" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
          OnRowDataBound="ProductList_OnRowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField 
        HeaderText="Productno." 
        DataField="ProductNumber"/>

    <asp:BoundField 
        HeaderText="Product" 
        DataField="Name" />

    <asp:BoundField 
        HeaderText="Price/Unit" 
        DataField="Price" />

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price/Unit Decimal">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price.Value") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>

  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: noew im getting `DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Value'.` looks like there is a problem at assining the Property

Comment: If `Price` is a `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money` object the `Value` property will bind correctly. Try to bind only price in this way `Bind("Price")` and check the output

Comment: it is an Money Type, see my edit. I stll get the Type instead of its value :-(

Comment: the code you took from xrm.cs is not correct or doesn't belong to Product.Price, the right one is generated in this way (please copy and paste inside VS):



[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("price")]
  public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money Price
  {
   get
   {
    return this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Money>("price");
   }
   set
   {
    this.OnPropertyChanging("Price");
    this.SetAttributeValue("price", value);
    this.OnPropertyChanged("Price");
   }
  }

Comment: Unfortunately this has not helped me, but i found out that wen im not creating a new Product(select) then it wirks fine. Is there a better way to get the products related to a pricelist?